# Express "Can't set headers after they are sent" for a file download

Tags: node.js

I've recently discovered a bug in an Express application that generates an error and crashes a nodejs under certain circumstances.

I have the following snipped configured for a certain application endpoint (e.g. GET /pdf)

```
app.get('/pdf/',function(req, res) {
  myPdfBuilder.buildPdf(pdfOptions, function(doc,err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500); res.end("Error");
    }
    else {
      res.contentType("application/pdf");
      res.attachment("my.pdf");
      doc.output(function(out) {
        res.end(out, 'binary');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The buildPdf function uses pdfkit (0.1.9) to render a PDF object, which is then read and the output is sent to res (aka "response").

If I access the endpoint, the PDF is successfully downloaded. I see the response headers being set:

```
Connection: keep-alive
content-disposition: attachment; filename=my.pdf
content-type: application/pdf
```

But if I try download a 2nd time, the application has an exception:

```
http.js:692
  throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
```

And the stack trace includes a reference to the line of `res.contentType("application/pdf")`

Any idea why the application crashes on the 2nd request to the download object? The nodejs process locks up and has to be killed and restarted (SIGKILL, SIGTERM does nothing).

express is version 2.5.11, with connect 1.9.2

Comment: Can you show your app.get handler for /pdf?

Comment: From this code everything looks fine. Do you have any other middleware attachet that can do anything with response? Also, you can try to use: re.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); res.send(out) (if out is buffer).

Comment: res.set or res.setHeader? I have tried the setHeader approach (and using a content-disposition header manually instead of res.attachment). I'm wondering if it may be environmental - the application is running in AWS behind an Elastic Load Balancer

Comment: We are always using res.set and res.send or res.render from express (it's rather a convention in our project) and as far I saw this error only once and it was our fault that we were not removing listeners. Unfortunatelly I can say notihng about AWS and his behaviour regarding this problem.

Comment: The problem is not related to AWS - I get the same behaviour when running the application locally - http://localhost:myport/pdf. the connection to the endpoint is keep-alive, and I also tried setting res.setHeader("Connection", "close") - but still doing the same thing. First request passes, and 2nd request fails.

Comment: After some additional debugging, I seem to have found the cause of the issue - it seems to be an issue with state in the application - the "myPdfBuilder" library is a custom PDF builder using PDFKit. It looks like the "myPdfBuilder.buildPdf" function is called multiple times on the second request, looks like the first instance is still in memory. I should probably refactor it to a class.